# How can I check if a device is managed through NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

How can I distinquish if a device (ethernet in this case) is managed by the NetworkManager?

At first I execute,

```
$ nmcli device 
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s3  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

where I see that the ethernet is connected but it doesn't tell me if the device is managed or not. The default is `false` inside `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` so I changed it to `true` and restart the service,

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
$ nmcli device 
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s3  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

but again I don't see specific info that ethernet is managed or not.

Comment: Reset `managed=true` back to false. `grep -i renderer /etc/netplan/*.yaml` will tell you if NetworkManager has been chosen. Also, your ethernet would show up as disabled if somebody wasn't managing it.

Comment: NetworkManager is indeed chosen, does that makes `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` obsolete? @heynnema

Comment: No. It's just that some NM stuff isn't described very much... just like some of the netplan stuff. While we're at it, show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: It doesn't exist @heynnema

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04 LTS (running from VirtualBox)

Comment: Btw `nmcli` behaves quite different on different distros (at least Ubuntu vsCentOS).

Comment: Remember... `nmcli` is *network manager command line interface*. I don't know what/how it works in CentOS :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -i renderer /etc/netplan/*.yaml` will tell you if NetworkManager has been chosen. Also, your ethernet would show up as **disabled** or **unmanaged** if somebody wasn't managing it.

Create this file...

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

add the following...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Reboot, or restart NetworkManager. Then `nmcli device` should show `lo` as managed. `lo` is the loopback device.